# Memory management with changing rootViewController of window

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am changing rootViewController of window dynamically in my application in Non - ARC application.

My question is do i need to release previously assigned rootViewController? How memory is management is done with previously allocated rootViewController?

My Second question is about newrootViewController. how i can manage memory for new rootViewController for window.

Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: You should use ARC! You can turn it on per-file if you can't use it everywhere. Just turn it on for this class where you're dealing with the root view controller (it doesn't have to be on for the view controller, just the class where you change it). Add the compile option `-fobjc-arc` just to that one translation unit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason is right in his comment above, in reality there are very few reasons not to use ARC. Automatic reference counting is just as efficient if not more so than manual reference counting.

Remember it's not garbage collection, the retain and release statements are simply added at compile time.

To answer your question, if you called `alloc` / `new` or `copy` on the rootViewController then **yes** you must release the previously allocated controller.

Remember being a memory management snob is not a sufficient reason to not use ARC! ;)

With regard to the newRootViewController object, as soon as you make it the windows 'root view controller' the window retains it, so you can then release it.

Take a look at this question also: [Retaining rootViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565409/retaining-rootviewcontroller)