# Is previous ViewController release the memory after changing the Rootviewcontroller programmatically?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have query related to memory management in iOS. When i login to the particular app and i carry the Registration process and after the 4 screen ,i have to jump into the home screen.so i don't need the previous 4 screens. so i call this below method

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *root=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"trend_navigation"];
appdelegate.window.rootViewController = root;
[appdelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

My question is, the previous screens are still present in back of the home screen or that will be release memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101595/memory-management-with-changing-rootviewcontroller-of-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no other strong references to your view controllers or any structure they allocated, yes, they will be automatically released (provided you use ARC, which is the default, of course).

Note that there could be many reasons for your view controllers to remain in memory, including any non-invalidated timers, block references, etc.

You can use **Instruments** to check if your objects are correctly released.

Comment: If strong reference present in the previous viewcontrollers , how can it release its memory automatically? or we have to release it ? how?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have strong references **from** your view controllers. It matters if you have strong references **to** your view controllers. If you have any such references, you just need to clear them (`variableVariableThatIsAStrongReferenceToTheViewController = nil`) when you no longer need it.

Comment: Note that in most cases, there shouldn't be any reason for you to have any strong reference to a view controller.